# NEO4J - Best practices to store 40 millions of text nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been using Neo4j for some weeks and I think it's awesome.

I'm building an NLP application, and basically, I'm using Neo4j for storing the dependency graph generated by a semantic parser, something like this:

https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=Hi%20dear%2C%20what%20is%20your%20name%3F&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=0

In the nodes, I store the single words contained in the sentences, and I connect them through relations with a number of different types.

For my application, I have the requirement to find all the nodes that contain a given word, so basically I have to search through all the nodes, finding those that contain the input word.  Of course, I've already created an index on the word text field.

I'm working on a very big dataset:

On my laptop, the following query takes about 20 ms:

```
 MATCH (t:token) WHERE t.text="avoid" RETURN t.text
```

Here are the details of the graph.db:

47.108.544 nodes

45.442.034 relationships

13.39 GiB db size

Index created on token.text field

```
PROFILE MATCH (t:token) WHERE t.text="switch" RETURN t.text

------------------------
NodeIndexSeek
251,679 db hits
---------------
Projection
251,678 db hits
--------------
ProduceResults
251,678 db hits 
---------------
```

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong in indexing such amount of nodes. At the moment, I create a new node for each word I encounter in the text, even if the text is the same of other nodes.

Should I create a new node only when a new word is encountered, managing the sentence structures through relationships?

Could you please help me with a suggestion or best practice to adopt for this specific case?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you ever have a look at https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-nlp ?

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, each of your :Token nodes should be unique. When you create these you should be using MERGE instead of CREATE for the node itself, so if the node already exists it will use the existing one rather than creating a new one.

It may help to also add a unique constraint for this after you've cleaned up your data.